# How to update an NSFileWrapper?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsfilewrapper

I have an `NSFileWrapper` with some content. I want to save it (`writeToURL...:`), add new content to it and **save it again**.

I would like to avoid writing again and again the same files. So, if I understood clearly, it means the option `NSFileWrapperWritingAtomic` is not for me. Especially as I save the file wrapper in the method

```
- (BOOL)writeAdditionalContent:(id)content
                         toURL:(NSURL *)absoluteURL
           originalContentsURL:(NSURL *)absoluteOriginalContentsURL
                         error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
```

(of an `OSX` analogue of `UIManagedDocument`)

and as Apple [says](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSFileWrapper_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSFileWrapperWritingOptions) "don't use this option in an override of `-[NSDocument writeToURL:ofType:error:]`".

So, I don't use this option, but updating the files from the file wrapper (I mean : saving again) fails (see below). Any idea/clue ?

---

### Here is what I do :

#### 1

I save it a first time with

```
[self.fileWrapper writeToURL:[absoluteURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"attached_files/"]
                     options:0
         originalContentsURL:[absoluteOriginalContentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"attached_files/"]
                       error:error] ;
```

It works well.

My file wrapper is

```
    /*
     Initializing the file wrapper
     */
    _fileWrapper = [[NSFileWrapper alloc] initDirectoryWithFileWrappers:nil] ;
    [_fileWrapper setFilename:@"attached_files"] ;
    [_fileWrapper setPreferredFilename:@"attached_files"] ;
```

#### 2

I save a second time with the same command. I get the error

```
 Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "The file already exists".
```

The given name is actually "attached_files".

#### 3

If I use the option `NSFileWrapperWritingWithNameUpdating`, I still get the same error.

#### 4

If I use the option `NSFileWrapperWritingAtomic`, I don't get errors.

Comment: why not to directly update the file?

Comment: I can't write directly in the document's file. Otherwise, the application will complain that the file has been modified by another application.

Comment: The compiler that ships with Xcode 7 throws a warning with this code: `Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument` for `-[NSFileWrapper initDirectoryWithFileWrappers:]`.